# Need help figuring out css hover animation

Tags: css

I am trying to have the dashed circle spin 360 degrees for 1 count while hovering over the 3 lined menu icon. I would like to do this with only css and html if possible. Here's what I've got, i can't seem to figure it out.
New to stackoverflow, just added snippet

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  //border: 1px solid white;
}
#dashed {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px dashed white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#menuIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 42.5px;
  width: 136px;
}
 #top {
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}
 #mid {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}
#bottom {
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}
#menuIcon:hover #dashed {
  animation: spin .8s 1;
}
@keyframes spin {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="dashed"></div>
  <div id="menuIcon">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="mid"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to catch an element on hovering over a different element, you need to add '~' or '+'

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  //border: 1px solid white;
}
#dashed {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px dashed white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#menuIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 42.5px;
  width: 136px;
}
 #top {
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}
 #mid {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}
#bottom {
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}
#menuIcon:hover + #dashed {
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.8s 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);

}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div id="menuIcon">
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="mid"></div>
        <div id="bottom"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="dashed"></div>
    </div>
```